# Проблемы с .slidedown

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Здравствуйте, недавно учу jquery и столкнулся со следующей проблемой:

```js
$('#leta').click(function() {
  $('#hide').slideDown('slow');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='col-lg-4' id='leta'>A</div>
<div data-scroll class='col-lg-12' id='hide' style='display:none'>B</div>
```

По клику на 'A' не происходит абсолютным счетом ничего

Comment: Перенес ваш код в сниппет - проблема не наблюдается.

Comment: @br3t может дело в стилях?

Comment: Вам достаточно проинспектировать ваш #hide в любом браузерном отладчике. + посмотреть ошибки в консоли.

Comment: @br3t Я что-то совсем ничего не понимаю 
Глянул ошибку, написано Bootstrap's Javascript requires Jquery 
Но я абсолютно точно его подключил

Comment: Мб вы подключили его после bootstrap.js?

Comment: @br3t Да, именно, спасибо

Answer (score -1):

1) Советую скачать jquery c http://jquery.com/ и подключить его в шаблоне
2) Немного не по задаче, но не используйте айдишники! (#leta, #hide) используйте классы. 
3) `<div data-scroll class='col-lg-12' id='hide' style='display:none'>B</div>`
   Инлайновый стиль лучше перенести в файл .css 
4) $('#leta').click(function() {
   Вместо click используйте

```
$('#leta').on('click', function() {$('#hide').slideDown();});
```

Comment: Чем плохи idшники? Почему уже тогда не `$('body').on('click', '#leta',...)`?

Comment: $('body').on('click', '#leta',...)? Это вообще к чему? А ответ на вопрос: потому что айдишники дольше рендерятся это раз. Второе айдишники захламляют css код. Третье это старье, т.к. сейчас работа front-end разработчика заключается в том, чтобы как можно максимально оптимизировать css код, это одна из главнейших задач

Comment: Вячеслав, код относился к вашему пункту 4

Comment: А понятно, $('body').on('click', '#leta',...). можно и так, разницы особой нет. как кому удобно

Comment: Ты увидел 3 строчки кода и такой "не используйте id!!!", чтооо? Есть места, где они уместны, есть, где не уместны, нужно смотреть всю разметку, что бы знать где что уместно. И в плане скорости - в js есть 2 функции: "getElementsByClassName" и "getElementById", замечаем, что во втором случае возвращается не коллекция, а один элемент, ДУМАЕМ...

Comment: "getElementsByClassName" и "getElementById" в данном случае используется jquery а не нативный js, так что данный комментарий не уместен. И давно уже куча способов, для того чтобы избежать id во вьюхах, те же биндинги